# MVC grid with sorting, paging and searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know any article or tutorial how to create nice grid for mvc with functions like columns sorting, paging and searching for items inside the grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now the best option is Grid.MVC . which you can download from Nuget.
[image]

Website :https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/

Demo   :http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/

Tutorial :http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 9):

[Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)