# Searching not working in GridMvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

As per image attached when I click on red highlighted button on any field it does not open a popup(feature of GridMvc) for searching. Though sorting is working. I think there is something wrong in _Grid.cshtml partial view. Here is code-

```
@using GridMvc.Columns
@model GridMvc.IGrid
@if (Model == null) { return; }
@{
    var gridClinetId = "grid-mvc-" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Id) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : Model.Id);
}
<div id="@gridClinetId" class="grid-outer @(Model.EnablePaging ? "paged" : string.Empty)">
    @* Draw grid top items infomation panel *@
    <div class="grid-wrap">
        <table class="table table-striped grid-table" data-lang="@Model.Language">
            @* Draw grid header *@
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        @Html.Raw(column.HeaderRenderer.Render(column, column.Title))
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.ItemsCount == 0)
                {
                    <tr class="grid-empty-text">
                        <td colspan="@Model.Columns.Count()">
                            @Model.EmptyGridText
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (object item in Model.ItemsToDisplay)
                    {
                        <tr class="grid-row @Model.GetRowCssClasses(item)">
                            @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
                            {
                                @Html.Raw(column.CellRenderer.Render(column, column.GetCell(item).ToString()))
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @if (Model.EnablePaging && Model.Pager != null && Model.Pager.PageCount > 1)
        {
            <div class="grid-footer">
                <div class="grid-footer-info">
                    Displaying items @(((Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * Model.Pager.PageSize) + 1)
                    - @(((Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1) * Model.Pager.PageSize) + Model.DisplayingItemsCount)
                    (@Model.ItemsCount)
                </div>
                @Html.Partial("_GridPager", Model.Pager)
            </div>
        }
        @* Draw pager *@
    </div>
</div>
@* Init Grid.Mvc client script *@
<script>
    if (typeof (jQuery) != 'undefined' && typeof (jQuery.fn.gridmvc) != 'undefined') {
        var grid = $("#@gridClinetId").gridmvc();
        window.gridMvcControl = grid;//when using only 1 grid on the page
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Id))
        {
         <text>if (typeof (window.pageGrids) == 'undefined') window.pageGrids = {}; window.pageGrids\['@Model.Id'\] = grid;</text>
        }
    }
</script>]
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176738/mvc-grid-with-sorting-paging-and-searching

Comment: I too already have took help from your given link.

Comment: Any other help will be more welcome